# Average distance of a node from root in weighted quick union algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

```
Compute the average distance from a node to the root in a worst-case tree of 
2^n nodes built by the weighted quick union algorithm?
```

This is an exercise in Algorithm in C++(Robert Sedgewick).

I know the worst case distance but can someone suggest me correct way to compute average distance?

Worst case scenario is the merging of 2 tree with same number of nodes. lets say merge 2 tree each having 2^n nodes, resulting tree [=size 2^(**n+1**) nodes] will have **n+1 max** distance of any node from the root ( more than 1 after merge).

**In worst case-  if tree size is 2^n, distance from root to any of the node is always less than n.**

How can we calculate the average distance if the max distance is n for 2^n node tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case is as you said, you always add two trees of the same height. In order to achieve it, you need: 2 trees of height n-1, and to achieve it you need 4 trees of height n-2, ....

At the end, **you need n trees of height 1, n/2 trees of height 2, ..., 1 tree of height n**.

Since this is your homework, I will be done by hinting you how to continue:

**Use the prvious observation**, and follow the algorithm to build the trees and "achieve" worst case. Note how many leaves there are in each depth - if you build a tree this way [**start with examples of private cases**, n=1,2,3 and see how it "behaves"]

If you need to formally prove it - it should be probably done by induction on the height [n].